# How do I use "rebar ct" with a two application node?

Tags: erlang, rebar, common-test

I'm using `rebar` to compile my application. Actually, it's two applications:

```
deps/
apps/A/
apps/B/
apps/B/suites
```

...where `B` depends on `A`. This is correctly configured in `apps/B/src/B.app.src`. However, when I attempt to run `rebar ct`, it fails to test `B`, reporting that it can't find `A.app`.

Running `rebar ct` in verbose mode shows that it's setting the code search path (`-pa`) to include `apps/B/ebin`, and `deps/foo/ebin`, `deps/bar/ebin`, etc.

It is **not** including `apps/A/ebin`.

How do I use Common Test to test an Erlang "application" that's made up of multiple applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in apps/B/rebar.config

```
{lib_dirs, [
    ".."
]}.
```

or

```
{ct_extra_params, "-pa ../A/ebin"}.
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, if B depends on A, I would have two separate tests. One for A and mention it deps section of B of rebar config and write separate test cases for B and run only for B so that application A modules would be automatically taken care by rebar.